# ksh calculate percentage of a colum where values < 2

Tags: awk, ksh, percentage

I have a large file where the fourth column contains decimal based values. How can I calculate the percentage of records that are < 2 ?

```
test test test .001
test2 test2 test2 8.0993
test3 test3 test3 .00001
test4 test4 test4 1.001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk script will do it:

```
awk '{$4<2?l++:g++}END{printf "< 2 : %s %\n", l*100/(g+l); printf ">=2 : %s %", g*100/(g+l)}' your.file
```

For better readability place it a file:

*percent.awk:*

```
{ $4<2 ? l++ : g++ }
END {
    printf "<  2 : %s %\n", l*100/(g+l)
    printf ">= 2 : %s %", g*100/(g+l)
}
```

and execute it like:

```
awk -f percent.awk your.file
```

Comment: Just some golfing: `{if($4>2){g++}else{l++}}` can change to: `{$4>2?g++:l++}`

Comment: In the END block, NR == g+l, so you can simplify to `$4<2{l++} END {...}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks for your comment :) you are right, let me check later if can be used to simplify it. I'm currenty in the middle of a task ...